# How do I add margin spacing between two inline buttons (BTN) in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am a new coder learning HTML and CSS.

I have coded two BTN into my HTML project but they are lodged together inline which looks daft.

How can I add margin spacing between them please so the aesthetics look proper.

[image]

> My HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Boutique Recruitment Solutions</h1>
        <p class="lead">We are an indapendant recruitment company specialising in providing bespoke HR services.<br> We take the time to understand our clients vision, goals and culture allowing us to engage with the right talent to fill the vacany.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Submit Your CV</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Fill A Vacancy</a></p>
      </div>
```

Comment: in the css. please specify

Comment: The buttons look like they have the `inline-block` property applied so margins should work on these? Can we see the CSS for the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think margin wouldn't work?

```css
a.btn {
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Boutique Recruitment Solutions</h1>
  <p class="lead">We are an indapendant recruitment company specialising in providing bespoke HR services.
    <br>We take the time to understand our clients vision, goals and culture allowing us to engage with the right talent to fill the vacany.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Submit Your CV</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Fill A Vacancy</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate that. Thank you for the steering. will upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Just use margin attribute.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Boutique Recruitment Solutions</h1>
        <p class="lead">We are an indapendant recruitment company specialising in providing bespoke HR services.<br> We take the time to understand our clients vision, goals and culture allowing us to engage with the right talent to fill the vacany.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" style="margin-right: 100px">Submit Your CV</a><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Fill A Vacancy</a></p>
      </div>
```